# Move layered navigation block between product list toolbar and product list

Tags: category, layout, xml, layered-navigation

I have moved the layered navigation block into the content section however I can't figure out how to position the block. I can only get it to show at the very top of the page or the bottom. I need it before the product listing and after the toolbar. So far my xml looks like this:

```
 <reference name="content">
     <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="product_list" after="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

But that doesn't seem to be working. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason your layered navigation only shows up at the bottom or at the top of the page is that you add the block at the wrong block "level".

You added the block to the block `content` which only has two direct child blocks: `category.products` and `product.tooltip`. Therefore you only can add your block at the top, between these two blocks or at the bottom.

**How to move the layered navigation between the product list toolbar and the product list**

Add this code to your **layout XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="left">
            <action method="unsetChild"><alias>catalog.leftnav</alias></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="product_list">
            <action method="insert"><blockName>catalog.leftnav</blockName></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
</layout>
```

This will **move** the layered navigation block from the left column **to the content column** without re-creating classes and the like. You can see I inserted the block as a child of the block `product_list`.

If you call the page now you will see that the layered navigation isn't displayed at all. That's because opposed to the `content` block, the `product_list` block doesn't output all child blocks by default. You have to echo the block yourself in the template file.

**Copy** `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` (replace base/default with your base theme if you use another one as your starting point) to your theme and tell Magento to **output** the layered navigation directly after the first toolbar:

```
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="category-products">
    <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('catalog.leftnav'); /* THIS IS THE NEW LINE */ ?>
    <?php // List mode ?>
```

You will get something like this and can go on from here:

[image: Layered navigation position between product list toolbar and product list]

Comment: Matthias, thanks so much for that. Worked like a charm.